# Can I put this division out?

Tags: c, char, integer, unsigned

I'm programming an app that does a huge amount of operations and I'm trying to optimize as much as I can.

I'm trying to put the division (31 / sum) outside test2 because this way I could do the operation just 1 time in one loop, otherwise it's done 3 times.

```
unsigned sum = 1234;
unsigned char test = 555;
unsigned char test2 = test * 31 / sum;
```

The goal would be

```
unsigned sum = 1234;
unsigned char test = 555;
unsigned division = 31 / sum;
unsigned char test2 = test * division;
```

Example of a real case (simplified) in C:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        unsigned a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0;
        int aux;

        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            aux = arr[j];
            if (conditions)
                a += aux;
            if (conditions)
                b += aux;
            if (conditions)
                c += aux;
            if (conditions)
                d += aux;
        }

        unsigned char ua = a, ub = b, uc = c, ud = d;
        unsigned sum = ua + ub + uc + ud + 1;
        unsigned_char_array_a[i] = ua * 31 / sum;
        unsigned_char_array_b[i] = ub * 31 / sum;
        unsigned_char_array_c[i] = uc * 31 / sum;
        unsigned_char_array_d[i] = ud * 31 / sum;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this invalid? `unsigned char test = 555;` on most machine `char` is 1 byte. Also I dont see any loop. Can you show more of the code?

Comment: `31 / sum` which is `31 / 1234` is always `0`.

Comment: It seems it's valid. The program was given to me as I wrote above. It must return the same values as the original one.

Comment: @WeatherVane the 1234 is an example value, it could be any unsigned integer

Comment: With integer arithmetic you should do the division last.

Comment: @WeatherVane so there's no way I can put it out?

Comment: Only when the numerator is a multiple of the denominator, or you are using floating point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210098/discussion-between-atenrevcode-and-weather-vane).

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Show us a realistic example. Your example values don't fit into an unsigned char, so instead of 1234 and 555, we're dealing with the values 43 and 210 here. If we assume ints, the value of `test2` is different in both cases.

Comment: I'm extending the question with details

Comment: if `test2()` calculates `x * 31 / y` you can do `31 * newtest2()` where `newtest2()` calculates `x / y`.

Comment: You don't need to ask man, you can put wherever you want.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica updated with more details

Comment: `unsigned sum = ua + ub + uc + ud + 1; sum /= 31;     unsigned_char_array_a[i] = ua  / sum;` is closeer.  Need to ponder.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I've tried this last one but the benchmarks are quite the same due to the extra instructions from the conversions from unsigned to float and vice versa.

Comment: @Eraklon `unsigned char` is always 1 byte, and on **most machines** a byte is an octet, fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

OP appears to be wanting to avoid integer division - something some (embedded) processors are slow at - even though they have fast multiplication.

```
  // 4 divisions.
  unsigned sum = ua + ub + uc + ud + 1;
  unsigned_char_array_a[i] = ua * 31 / sum;
  unsigned_char_array_b[i] = ub * 31 / sum;
  ...
```

Given `sum` will have a value in the [1-1021] range, code could do a scaled multiplication and then a division by a constant power-of-2.  Good compilers will effect a simple fast shift.  With a 32-bit `int/unsigned`:

Scale by 65536

```
  #define SCALE 65536u

  unsigned factor = (31 * SCALE)/sum;
  unsigned_char_array_a[i] = (ua * factor) / SCALE;
  unsigned_char_array_b[i] = (ub * factor) / SCALE;
  ...
```

Untested assertion: I do not expect the exact same quotient every time as `(ua * 31) / sum;`, but will be within 1.

Comment: That works and saves some ms but the error, despite being as small as 1, accumulates and the final result is different than the expected one.